# Remove ALMOST repeats in a perl Array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array with the following elements:

```
my @array = ("\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:44 AM PST",
"\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:47 AM MST",
"\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:49 AM MST",
"\"Apple in Pie\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 10:22:32 AM MST",
"\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:51 AM MST",
"\"Rock in Out\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 11:17:41 AM PST")
```

I want to sort this array so that all elements with a repeated string (inside the "") will be removed. The reason why this is a little unique is because the time associated with each string is a little different, but not much.

Here is what I want the output to look like:

```
"\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:49 AM MST",
"\"Apple in Pie\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 10:22:32 AM MST",
"\"Rock in Out\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 11:17:41 AM PST"
```

I don't really care about sorting the time, just removing the repeats inside the "".

This was my thought process so far:

```
    my @row;
    foreach my $row (@array) {
        my $name = $row;
        $name =~ s/\son.*//;
        next if (grep {$_ =~ /($name)/} @row);
        push(@row,$row);
    }
```

There has to be a better way to do this. Also, I am having issues with my method (the grep doesn't seem to be working as intended, it won't go to the next statement).

Comment: Using a hash to check for duplicates is the idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following assigns a list without duplicates to `@filtered`:

```
my %seen;
my @filtered = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @array;
```

In your case, a minor tweek is needed. The substring between quotes is what determines if you've already seen that item, so it needs to be used in lieu of `$_`.

```
my %seen;
my @filtered = grep { /^"([^"]+)"/ && !$seen{$1}++ } @array;
```

Comment: Bonus: This method preserves the input's order (while `keys %seen` doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

For duplicate detection, a hash is the tool for the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = (
    "\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:44 AM PST",
    "\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:47 AM MST",
    "\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:49 AM MST",
    "\"Apple in Pie\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 10:22:32 AM MST",
    "\"Foo in Bar\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 08:07:51 AM MST",
    "\"Rock in Out\" on Mon 09 Feb 2015 11:17:41 AM PST"
);

my %seen;

foreach my $element (@array) {
    my ($first_bit) = ( $element =~ m/^(.*) on/ );
    $seen{$first_bit} = $element;
}

foreach my $first_bit ( keys %seen ) {
    print $seen{$first_bit}, "\n";
}
```

We iterate the array, selecting the 'first bit' out of the string (I'm grabbing anything in front of 'on' in this example - you may want to match something different).

By using that as a hash key, and duplicates overwrite, and then we just print one element. You could test for existence of `$seen{$first_bit}` if you want the first occurrence, rather than the last. You could use `Time::Piece` to parse dates and sort if that was important to you.

Comment: I am interested in adding the Time::Piece to parse dates. Is there a quick and easy method to doing this? I can't seem to find any clear examples around.

Comment: There's a section on it in the man page: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.29/Piece.pm#Date_Parsing - it supports `strptime` which'll turn a formatted time into a numeric representation